# addUniqueConstraint with where clause in liquibase

Tags: sql, where-clause, liquibase

I want to convert this sql query

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNQ_ALERT_NAME
            ON alert_configuration(name, account_id)
            WHERE
            (status != 'Deleted')
```

to liquibase changeset like given below

```
    <changeSet author="kusum" id="alertconfig-unique-index-4.1.0"">
<addUniqueConstraint
        columnNames="name, account_id, tournament_id"
        constraintName="UNQ_ALERT_NAME"
        tableName="alert_configuration"
        />
</changeSet>
```

Not sure where this "where clause" could be added for addUniqueConstraint? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Liquibase does not support that. You need to use a `<sql>` change and write the complete CREATE INDEX there

Answer (score 2):

There is no liquibase syntax for this so you have to use the SQL tags:

```
<changeSet author="kusum" id="alertconfig-unique-index-4.1.0"">
    <SQL> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNQ_ALERT_NAME
            ON alert_configuration(name, account_id)
            WHERE
            (status != 'Deleted') </SQL>
</changeSet>
```